# My boy, my woman, my man, my girl

Tags: idiom

What would be the meaning for "my girl", "my man", "my boy", "my woman" in Latin?

If I use *filia tua*, it means you daughter, but could be used as *puella tua* to mean the same, or is there other implied meaning when using this kind of structures in Latin?

For instance, French language use "ma femme" litt. "my woman" to say "my wife", but "mon garçon" is not always a son, but can be an expression to express either affection or paternalism.

In English, using "my girl" means my girlfriend (I think).

And, in French, you would have a different meaning if you use "la fille" (a girl) or "ma fille" (my daughter).

So, what are the possible meanings and use of such phrases?

Answer (score 3):

Another quite possible meaning of *puer meus* or *puella mea* would be "my servant (or slave)".  I don't recall ever seeing *mulier mea* used for "my wife"; for that *uxor* would be a lot more common.